# Limit Pickup Dates in Date Picker

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am building an online store using Shopify. My business is a food production business. My access to a commercial kitchen is limited to one day a week (Sunday) so I intend to collect orders Monday-Saturday, cook on Sunday, and have the orders available for pickup thereafter. I already have much of the code that I need loaded into my Shopify theme. To start off, I used the custom code at this LINK https://shopify.dev/tutorials/customize-theme-add-date-picker-for-delivery-dates

However I need further customization...

I need help customizing the Date Picker available dates based on the day of the week that the order is placed.

Rules below:

- An order placed Monday-Saturday, could be picked up as early as Monday next week and any day after that, but not sooner;
- An order placed on Sunday cannot be picked up until the following Monday (not the next day), but could be picked up on any day after that;
- No pickups on Sundays at all

EXAMPLE:

- Monday 5/10 - earliest pickup Monday 5/17
- Tuesday 5/11 - earliest pickup Monday 5/17
- Wednesday 5/12 -  earliest pickup Monday 5/17
- Thursday 5/13 -  earliest pickup Monday 5/17
- Friday 5/14 -  earliest pickup Monday 5/17
- Saturday 5/15 -  earliest pickup Monday 5/17
- Sunday 5/16 -  earliest pickup Monday 5/24
- No pickups on Sundays

Answer (score 0):

You can try using datepicker's `beforeShowDay` function to restrict available days like so:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  if (window.jQuery) {
    let $ = window.jQuery;
    let today = new Date();
    let next_week = today.getTime() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    $(function() {
      $("#date").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var day_of_week = date.getDay();
         
            //disable all dates in the past, disable all days of the week after today's day of the week but within 7 days
            if (date.getTime() <= today.getTime() || (day_of_week > today.getDay() && date.getTime() < next_week)) {
                return [false, ""];
            }
            
            //disable all sundays
            return [(day_of_week != 0), ""];
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<div style="width:300px; clear:both;">
    <p>
      <label for="date">Pick a delivery date:</label>
      <input id="date" type="text" name="attributes[date]" value="{{ cart.attributes.date }}" />
      <span style="display:block" class="instructions"> We do not deliver on Sundays.</span>
    </p>
</div>
```